# Unable to use TouchImageView with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, pinchzoom

In the following code i display images with swipe action and on Tap buttons using ViewPager and ImageView. But It doesn't allow me to Zoom/Pan images. 
For that i got tried using TouchImageView, bt didn't succedded. My original activity is as follows:

```
package com.pankajvatsa.testfeet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ImageViewPager extends Activity {
// Declare Variable
int position;
Button bWallpaperButton;
Button bDownloadButton;
RelativeLayout mainLay;
int flagForButton = 0;
boolean gone = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set title for the ViewPager
    setTitle("ViewPager");
    // Get the view from view_pager.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_view_pager);

    bWallpaperButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetWallpaper);
    bDownloadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSaveToGallery);

    mainLay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_view_pager);

    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
    Intent p = getIntent();
    position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");

    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    // Retrieve all the images
    for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        images.add(imageView);
    }

    // Set the images into ViewPager
    ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
    ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.image_pager);
    viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
    // Show images following the position
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

    viewpager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


        private float pointX;
        private float pointY;
        private int tolerance = 50;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                pointX = event.getX();
                pointY = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                boolean sameX = pointX + tolerance > event.getX() && pointX - tolerance < event.getX();
                boolean sameY = pointY + tolerance > event.getY() && pointY - tolerance < event.getY();
                if(sameX && sameY){
                        //The user "clicked" certain point in the screen or just returned to the same position an raised the finger

                    if(gone == false){
                        bWallpaperButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        bDownloadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gone = true;
                    }else{
                        bWallpaperButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        bDownloadButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        gone = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
    });


}

}
```

After this I created a new class in my package named 'TouchImageView.java' and pasted the code of TouchImageView in it. Then i replaced the type ImageView in the above code with TouchImageView.
When i launched the application, i still couldn't zoom the images and moreover, the buttons which used to appear on tap also don't appear now.

Please Help!!!

Comment: Try using it outside of a `ViewPager`, or try doing vertical pinches instead of horizontal ones. If your problem persists, then the issue is that `ViewPager` eats the touch events, and you will need to subclass `ViewPager` and override `canScroll()` to address this.

Answer (score 2):

I know this questions is old but at the time of this answer Mike has already updated TouchImageView with support for ViewPager (you may need to switch to the dev branch)

Comment: can u please help me how to use Pager with TouchImageView

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use **[Android Touch Gallery](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery)**. Have a look at library. Having `ViewPager` as gallery and `Touch Image View` inside which enables pinch zoom and pan.